# timepicker is not changing after click

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the  timepicker http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/index.html

In my form I validate the input values its working for all values except the departure_time.

I have a datepicker and it works well but with time it doesnt do anything.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
  var validator = $('#commentForm').validate({
    rules: {
       departure_time: {
        required: true
      }
    }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#sample1 input').ptTimeSelect();
        });
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#sample2 input').ptTimeSelect();
        });

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#departure_time").focus(function(){
        console.log($(this).valid());
    });
});

$(document).on('change','input',function(){
//alert('testinput');
    console.log($(this).valid());
});

</script>

<div id="sample1" class="ui-widget-content" >
     <input name="departure_time" size="35" value="" id="departure_time"  data-error="#errNm10" />
<div class="errorTxt">
<span id="errNm10"></span><br>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have various issue in your html.

1) Validate plugin is missing in the end `});`

2) There is no `<form id="commentForm">`

3) `jQuery(function($) {` is missing closing `});`

Once you are done with the above changes everything works fine. Below is the updated fiddle.

UPDATED FIDDLE - https://jsfiddle.net/j813ntb6/

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var validator = $('#commentForm').validate({
         rules: {
            departure_time: {
            required: true
            }
         }
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sample1 input').ptTimeSelect();
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sample2 input').ptTimeSelect();
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#departure_time").focus(function(){
            console.log($(this).valid());
        });
    });

     $(document).on('change','input',function(){
        //alert('testinput');
        console.log($(this).valid());
    });
});
```

Comment: i have made the changes the difference is in console.log($(this).valid()); i get FALSE when i click on the timepicker, datepicker i get true, I have to click twice on the timepicker so it will work

Comment: What do you mean ? can you explain more ?

Comment: on the console log(using firefox) when i click on the timepicker i should get    'true' but i get 'false' from the timepicker, i have to click on it twice so it will get 'true'

Comment: are you referring to my jsfiddle ? I get "true" when i click on the textbox and then select time and click "set".